# Identifying the class in which code is running

Tags: python, metaprogramming

In the below code, can someone please tell me, at the line marked `#whereami` (line 3), how I can identify that I am now in a class Person rather than in the instantiated Programmer object.

Ideally I'd like a class/type object but the class name 'Person' will do if that cannot be returned.

```
class Person(object):
    def opinion(self):
        #whereami
        print "Time for a cup of tea"

class Programmer(Person):
    def opinion(self):
        super(Programmer, self).opinion()
        print "There is no spoon"

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    programmer = Programmer()
    programmer.opinion()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
type('object')
```

See example below using Python3.2

```
class Person(object):
    def opinion(self):
        print(type(self))
        print ("Time for a cup of tea")

class Programmer(Person):
    def opinion(self):
        super(Programmer, self).opinion()
        print ("There is no spoon")

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    programmer = Programmer()
    programmer.opinion()

p = Person()
p.opinion()
print('\n')
pg = Programmer()
pg.opinion()
```

**Results**

```
<class '__main__.Person'>
Time for a cup of tea


<class '__main__.Programmer'>
Time for a cup of tea
There is no spoon
```

You can tell that the first result was called by the "Person" class.

Comment: Thank you. There's no other way the same information is accessible?

Answer (score 1):

try inserting the following line

```
className=self.__class__.__name__
```

The className variable would have the value of the current class name as a string